# error: you need to resolve your current index first plugins/macos/spotify: needs merge

Tags: plugins, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am trying to uninstall a zsh plugin (`macos`), I have modified the `.zshrc` file and removed `macos` from the `plugin` list, and deleted the `macos` file in path `~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins`, but now when ever I initialize `zsh`, the following error always come out. How do I fix this?

`error: you need to resolve your current index first plugins/macos/spotify: needs merge`

Comment: I've also tried `brew cleanup` and `brew doctor`, those didn't work. Furthermore, I can't `upgrade_oh_my_zsh` due to the error above.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just reset it:

```
cd ~/.oh-my-zsh; git reset --hard
```

Comment: what are the consequences of `git reset --hard`?

Comment: It worked in my case, although I am not sure what I have to reconfigure afterwards

Comment: Be careful of this one - I'd rather not nuke all my custom changes back to factory defaults. See https://www.gitkraken.com/learn/git/git-reset#git-reset-hard-to-discard-working-directory-and-index-changes